# Insertar registro con PDO/php

Tags: php

He hecho un formulario pero solo puedo insertar datos pero no usar una variable por ejemplo que sera incluida en el formulario al ser mandado:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
try{
$database_connection = database_connect();
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
$users = $database_connection->query('SELECT * FROM coffee')->fetchAll();

$title = 'Home';
$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<form method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="fname" required placeholder="First Name"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" required placeholder="Last Name"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="age" required placeholder="Age" min="10" > </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="insert"></input></td>
</br>
</tr>
</form></table>
<br>
';
$content .=  '<br><table>';
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{


// get values form input text and number
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

$uso = $database_connection->query('INSERT INTO coffee(id) VALUES(fname)');

}else{
    echo "nothing";
}
foreach($users as $user) {

    $content .= '<tr>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $user["id"] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $user["type"] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $user["price"] . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td><a href="index.php">' . $user["price"] . '<a/></td>';
    $content .= '<td><a href="index.php">' . $user["price"] . '<a/></td>';
    $content .= '</tr>';
}




$content .=  '</table>';

include 'Template.php';
?>
```

Es basicamente que no puedo usar :fname, :lname, :age alguna solucion a este problema¿

Comment: De qué tipo es el campo "id" de la tabla coffee? Por otro lado, el valor que le estás pasando, de ser un texto, no está formateado correctamente. En caso de ser un parámetro, no lo estás asociando en ninguna parte.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de php, podría ser algo así:

```
$uso = $database_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO COFFEE (fname, lname, age) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :age)");
$uso->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
$uso->bindParam(':lname', $lname);
$uso->bindParam(':age', $age);
$uso->execute();
```

Puedes ver más ejemplos en el siguiente enlace: http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: no me funciona en mi caso

Comment: Necesitamos un poco más de información para poder ayudar.

Comment: pongo al codigo :fname es decir el input que introduce y me da el error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fname' in 'field list'' in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 46 un salu2

Comment: El mensaje es bastante explícito: El campo 'fname' no existe en la tabla.

Comment: perdona me equivoque de error el error es este Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 ' in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 46
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 in C:\wamp\www\www\tool.php on line 46

Comment: disculpa de nuevo esque no se como aparecio fname sino me hubiera dado cuenta es PDOException lo que me da

Comment: cuando capturo la excepcion es este error : Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 El problema es al poner una variable de este tipo con el insert into $uso = $database_connection->query('INSERT INTO coffee (id) VALUES(:fname)');

Comment: El método query no es para insertar, por favor mira bien el ejemplo y la documentación.

Comment: intente esta manera con prepare $uso = $database_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO coffee (id) VALUES(:fname)'); pero no inserta nada

Comment: perdon por lo del query

Comment: en query me lo hace pero cuando uso la variable obviamente no lo hace

Comment: `$uso->execute()` no te funciona?